# EF Core: Query could not be translated - but works fine in LinqPad

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a somewhat complex datamodel that looks like this:

A document can consist of other documents.
A document can be part of a project.
A document can have different revisions (generations), which are also documents that share the same key.
A document has a state (published or under editing etc.).

A project belongs to a release.
A project can have checklist and tasks.
Tasks are based on task templates.

I have a view in my database that connects this data and I'd like to get the latest version of all top-level documents (as well as the last published version of that document, if there is one) and the project they belong to (if there is an active one). And if there is a project, I also want to get the checklist, tasks and task templates.

My query looks something like this:

```csharp
var docs =
            (
                // Latest version of a top-level document
                from topLevelDoc in _dbContext.MyView
                    .Where(x => x.IsTopLevel)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.DocumentKey)
                    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Revision).First())
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Title)

                // Last released version of the same document
                let lastReleasedDoc = _dbContext.Document
                    .Where(x => x.DocumentKey == topLevelDoc.DocumentKey && x.State == "Released")
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Revision)
                    .FirstOrDefault()

                // The active project
                let project = _dbContext.Project.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                    x.Id == topLevelDoc.ProjectId && !new[] {"Complete", "Cancelled"}.Contains(x.State))

                // The release
                let release =
                    _dbContext.Release.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == project.ReleaseId)

                // The checklist
                let checklist = _dbContext.Checklist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == project.ChecklistId)

                let projectTasks =
                    (from projectTask in _dbContext.ProjectTask
                        join taskTemplate in _dbContext.TaskTemplate on projectTask.TaskTemplateId equals taskTemplate.Id
                        where projectTask.ProjectId == project.Id
                        select new {ProjectTask = projectTask, TaskTemplate = taskTemplate})

                select new TopLevelDocument
                {
                    // [...]

                    Project = project != null
                        ? new Project
                        {
                            // [...]
                            Release = new Release
                            {
                                // [...]
                            },
                            Checklist = checklist != null
                                ? new Checklist
                                {
                                    // [...]
                                }
                                : null,
                            Tasks = projectTasks.Select(x =>
                                new ProjectTask
                                {
                                    // [...]
                                    Template = new TaskTemplate
                                    {
                                        // [...]
                                    }
                                }
                            ).ToArray()
                        }
                        : null
                }
            ).ToArray();
```

While this works in LinqPad, EntityFramework Core 3.1.15 (I have to use .NET Framework and later versions don't seem to be compatible) is complaining:

```
'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (d.document_key), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: MyView Keyless
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Revision)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just for reference, I was able to fix this by creating a second view like this and querying that instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW
LatestRevisionView
AS
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM MyView
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Document_Key ORDER BY Revision DESC)
```

Comment: There is a hudge difference between v3 and 5. V3 takes all records from Db Server and after this create result. V5 is trying to create SQL  and send it to db Server.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no good solution?

Comment: At first you have to download on the server the records you need using ToList().  After this you can use any Linq functions including your own.

Comment: @Serge I prefer `AsEnumerable` to `ToList` which theoretically doesn't have to create another data structure. Also, v3 explicitly does not do automatic client side evaluation, that was the breaking change between v2 and v3. v5 is just a continuation of v3.

Comment: You need to use the same LINQ in LINQPad as you are for your program. If you are using .Net Framework, you need LINQPad v5 and then either connect an assembly or use LINQ to SQL, depending on what your program uses.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, you can AsEnumerable as well. After you get data from DB you can use any kind of LINQ